# Some mouse clicks don't register in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I've got a rather Javascript-heavy page with lots of contents generated via AJAX or other scripts. On some of these elements Selenium can record mouse clicks, while on others it ignores them. I haven't found any correlation. Perhaps there are some known common scenarios where Selenium cannot intercept mouse clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not all clicks in Selenium are equal. Some are mouseDown and MouseUp or a variation on that. I would play around with that to get your app working.

Unfortunately Selenium IDE has been misrepresented. It is a Record/Tweak/Playback tool not a record/playback tool.

Comment: I do understand the tweak phase, but I don't even get past the record phase. I click the element, my Javascript does its thing, but Selenium doesn't even stir.

Answer (score 1):

There's no list of actions that are unreliable. In my experience there's no pattern to which elements work, but it's consistent throughout executions of the test. In case you were thinking about it, playing around with locators or UI-Elements is very unlikely to improve your results.

I recently had a situation with a number of dropdown menus, all implemented in the same way, on multiple different pages. On certain pages, dropdown #2 and #3 wouldn't work, yet on other pages they would work, but dropdowns #1 and #2 wouldn't.

As has already been pointed out, the best thing to do is stop thinking about Selenium IDE as a record-playback tool.

---

On a sidenote, you may be asking this question for a similar reason I was, which was wanting to use Selenium IDE as a frontend for teammates without Selenium programming experience to create tests with, then one thing I did find helpful was extending the Selenium IDE by adding a [Command Builder](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/Writing+extensions), which allows you to control what appears in the right-click menu when using the IDE.

This means you can press record, go about recording your test as normal while keeping an eye on what has been recorded. Once you see Selenium IDE has failed to record an action, you can just right-click the element and the action you wanted to record will be easily available.

Not a solution to your original question, but it's helped me out. It's very simple to write an extension to the right-click menu, there's some really good examples on [this Selenium website.](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/Contributed+Extensions+and+Formats)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a 100% selenium noob, but I had the same problem and solved it through the following workaround:

- Right-click the to-be-clicked item
- Choose a random command that has the entire locator text, e.g. `assertText //div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div IR` or something. Look inside "Show all available commands" too.
- In the Selenium IDE, change the command to "click" and remove the 2nd argument (the Value field; if any)

Hacky, and should be easily improved with a custom command in the right-click menu, but for now this works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `clickAt` with location (0,0)? It sometimes helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have assigned an ID to the element you want to click I would suggest you try a simple script, you can perform this through the IDE:

`runScriptAndWait`

`jQuery("#yourButton").trigger('click');`

I have used this in the past and it works just fine.